# java script confirm box, it should remain on same page when cancel button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

we r having functionality, when  we edit the draft for specific job role.. It is redirecting to that edit draft page. This page has cancel button, on click of which we get confirmation box.. having msg ("Directing back to the previous page, changes made will not be saved.") also "OK" & "Cancel" button.

**My Problem**

In current code when I click on "OK" It is redirecting to parent page (which is correct) but when I click on "Cancel" button or cross mark of confirmation box, still its redirecting to the parent page (which is wrong) it should remain on the same edit page when I click on cancel button(or cross mark). I need help for this. Thanks.

```
****JS code for cancel button:****

jq("[data-dom-id=sdd-ejrp-btn-cancel]").click(function ()
 {
       var sdd_ejrp_btn_cancel = jq(this);
       if (confirm("Directing back to the previous page, changes made will not be saved.")) 
        {

        }
    });


    UI code in soy template:

<button data-dom-id="sdd-ejrp-btn-cancel" onclick="{if $pageId > 0}javascript: event.preventDefault(); window.location.href='{$baseUrl}/pages/viewpage.action?pageId={$pageId}'{/if}{if $pageId <= 0}javascript: event.preventDefault(); window.location.href='{$baseUrl}/pages/viewpage.action?pageId={$parentPageId}'{/if}" class="aui-button aui-button-link">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false;` if OK is not clicked. Below is the code:

```
jq("[data-dom-id=sdd-ejrp-btn-cancel]").click(function() {
  var sdd_ejrp_btn_cancel = jq(this);
  if (confirm("Directing back to the previous page, changes made will not be saved.")) {
     console.log("Clicked Yes!!.. It will redirect.");
  } else {
    console.log("It will stay here... ");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: @ Milan Chheda I tested with the changes.. its still redirecting to the previous page even if I clicked on "Cancel" or "cross mark"

Comment: @kosh very any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is using `<button>` inside a form. Whenever a click happened, the form will submit. Try changing `<button>` tag with `<span>` or other elements